# Angular Material 2 Autocomplete : search on change

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material for the first time, I'm using the Autocomplete tool to be precise.

I have a lot of data, and I don't want to show a list of options when selecting the input field. Instead of that, I want to perform a search every time the user types something in the field.

Here's my code :

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Sup bro" aria-label="Number" matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onSelectAdmin($event)" *ngFor="let administrateur of administrateurs" [value]="administrateur">
                    {{administrateur}}
                </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

So i'm wondering if it possible to do something like `*ngFor="let administrateur of searchAdministrateur($event)" [value]="administrateur">`

Of if there's any way I can call my search function everytime the text entry is changed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api):

`showPanel: boolean` is probably what you need.

> Whether the autocomplete panel should be visible, depending on option
>   length.

**Update**: 
Added [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nydrnm) sample with API call.

Comment: Ok but where do i call my searchAdministrateur function? This function performs a search using the entred text

Comment: @user you can attach the search to the input's value change

Comment: How? Actually that's what the actual question is about. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user I've attached a stackblitz sample, the idea is to add a valueChange to the input field